# got Exec Failure: HTTP 403 when submit spark on k8s

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes

- spark version: v2.4.0
- eks info: v1.10.11-eks

after submit, got wrong message as follow:

> 019-02-21 15:08:44 WARN  WatchConnectionManager:185 - Exec Failure: HTTP 403, Status: 403 - pods is forbidden: User "system:anonymous" cannot watch pods in the namespace "spark"
>   java.net.ProtocolException: Expected HTTP 101 response but was '403 Forbidden'
>
> Exception in thread "main" io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: pods is forbidden: User "system:anonymous" cannot watch pods in the namespace "spark"

Comment: You need to grant access to the specified user into the namespace or run the process as a new user who has that access.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create [Role](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#role-and-clusterrole) for system:anonymous user to watch pods on your namespace with similar to below yaml

```
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  namespace: spark # your namespace
  name: pod-reader # Role name will be needed for binding to user
rules:
- apiGroups: [""] # "" indicates the core API group
  resources: ["pods"]
  verbs: ["get", "watch", "list"]
```

Then you need to create [RoleBindging](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#role-and-clusterrole) to bind this role to **system:anonymous** user with similar to below yaml

```
# This role binding allows "system:anonymous" to read pods in the "spark" namespace.
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: read-pods
  namespace: spark # your namespace
subjects:
- kind: User
  name: system:anonymous # Name is case sensitive
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
roleRef:
  kind: Role #this must be Role or ClusterRole
  name: pod-reader # this must match the name of the Role or ClusterRole you wish to bind to
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

[Documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#anonymous-requests) for more info about Anonymous requests